# An ASCII histogram of a die rolled n times

Tags: c++, c++14, dice, ascii-art, data-visualization

A die is rolled n times. Each time, a random value has been inserted into a vector. This vector then is used to generate a sorted map (wrongly called hashmap in the code) that is later used to create an ASCII histogram.

The histogram, for example, looks like this:

```
    10
    #
    #
7   #
#   #
#   #     5
#   #     #
# 3 #     #
# # #     #
# # # 1   #
# # # #   #
-----------
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

And here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <map>

std::vector<int> roll(int times)
{
    std::vector<int> rand;

    while (times > 0)
    {
        std::random_device seeder;
        std::mt19937 engine(seeder());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 6);
        rand.push_back(dist(engine));

        --times;
    }

    return rand;

}

std::map<int, int> histogram_calculate(int times)
{
    std::vector<int> random_numbers = roll(times);


    std::map<int, int> cnt_hashmap;
    auto max_element = 6;

    for (int i = 1; i <= max_element; ++i)
    {
        cnt_hashmap[i] = 0;
    }

    for (auto iter = random_numbers.begin(); iter != random_numbers.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cnt_hashmap[*iter] += 1;
    }

    return cnt_hashmap;
}


std::string histogram_draw(int times)
{
    std::vector<std::string> ret_vec;
    std::map<int, int> histogram = histogram_calculate(times);

    for (int i = 1; i <= histogram.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::string to_add = "";

        if (histogram[i] > 0)
        {
            to_add = std::to_string(histogram[i]);
            std::string column = "\n";
            int j = 0;

            while (j <= histogram[i])
            {
                column += "#";
                column += "\n";

                ++j;
            }

            to_add += column;
        }

        to_add += "--";
        to_add += std::to_string(i);

        ret_vec.push_back(to_add);

    }

    std::string finalize = "";

    for (auto &str : ret_vec)
    {
        finalize += str;
    }

    return finalize;


}

int main() {

    std::cout << histogram_draw(10) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There's three functions:

- One to fill the random value vector
- One to sort out the histogram.
- One to display the histogram.

That's about it.

Comment: Welcome on Code Review. I afraid to tell you that your code don't match what's this site is about. Only working (as expected) full code can be reviewed. In fact, reading your code, I didn't understand how you computed columns drawing to get the expected result. Finally, I was right, it didn't. It's sad, there's many interesting things to tell about your code (randomization, map initialization, ...), but [you're off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you need help getting it working, maybe ask the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (the main site). Good luck

Comment: Here's your program [on Clang 4.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EP5edcoLroXJB4V4) and [on GCC 4.9.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LvOE53YHYoAPpa4o). Look at the given output.

Comment: As you seem unsure: one *die*, two (or more) *dice*.  Just think of it as a strange pronunciation of "dies"...

Comment: @Calak The output was a bit messy... I didn't know it would make my question off-topic. I fixed it. Is it still problematic? Should I fix it more?

Comment: @ChubakBidpaa The output wasn't just messy, but just completely different from the expected output. (If you want, I can give you an example that lead to the previously expected output.)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @rolfl can I add an alternative code?

Comment: @rolfl I think you misunderstood the reason for the edit. At revision 3, the code does not produce the expected output. So revision 3 is off-topic. At revision 5, the code functions as intended. So revision 5 is on-topic.

Comment: @Kerndog73 - the answer was given at 08:01 and revision 4 was made at 14:33 . It is revision 4 that invalidates the answer. This is not about on-topicness, it is about answer invalidation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `roll` function generates a random sequence of integers. The loop body shows me that you know how to seed a pseudo-RNG with a true source of randomness but you're doing it for every iteration. You should seed the pseudo-RNG once and then use it in the loop. You know how big your `rand` vector will be by the time you're done with it so you should `reserve` memory for it so that it the memory doesn't need to be reallocated as you push integers. So your `roll` function should probably look like this:

```
std::vector<int> roll(int times)
{
    std::vector<int> rand;
    rand.reserve(times);

    std::random_device seeder;
    std::mt19937 engine(seeder());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 6);

    while (times > 0)
    {
        rand.push_back(dist(engine));
        --times;
    }

    return rand;
}
```

---

The next function, `histrogram_calculate` creates a histogram. The histogram is stored in a `std::map<int, int>` which is not really the best choice. Think about what we're storing.

```
1 -> 7
2 -> 3
3 -> 10
4 -> 1
5 -> 0
6 -> 5
```

We want to know the frequency of six numbers. Since six is a compile-time constant, we could use a `std::array<int, 6>` instead. Initializing an array to zero is as simple as `histogram.fill(0)`. With a `std::map<int, int>` you need to set keys to zero in a loop.

```
auto max_element = 6;

for (int i = 1; i <= max_element; ++i)
{
    cnt_hashmap[i] = 0;
}
```

Using `auto` here is not a good idea. In fact, `int` is shorter and provides more information. Also, `max_element` should be a `const`ant since it doesn't actually change. The `max_element` variable is a good start but `6` should be available to the `roll` function as well. You should create a global constant for `6` or perhaps use a template parameter.

```
// The number of sides on a die
constexpr int num_sides = 6;
```

---

`histrogram_calculate` iterates the vector of random numbers and counts up the frequencies.

```
for (auto iter = random_numbers.begin(); iter != random_numbers.end(); ++iter)
{
    cnt_hashmap[*iter] += 1;
}
```

Here, you're using iterators when you could be using a range-for.

```
for (const int num : random_numbers) {
    cnt_hashmap[num]++;
}
```

---

Wait just a minute!

`histogram_calculate` makes a call to `roll` which returns a sequence of random integers but then, it's just thrown away! Do we really need the whole sequence in order to create a histogram?

No. We can create the histogram directly from the sequence of random numbers. There's no need to create an array and then just throw it away.

I'll let you try this yourself.

---

`histogram_draw` knows how to generate a histogram. `histogram_draw` should take a histogram and draw it. `histogram_draw` should have no idea where the histogram is coming from. `histrogram_draw` should just draw a histogram.

---

As @Calak pointed out in the comments, `histrogram_draw` doesn't actually behave as intended so this question is technically off-topic. Might I suggest that you write code to print a horizontal histogram? English text is typically written left-to-right so it is considerably easier to draw a horizontal histogram than a vertical one.

```
1 | ####### 7
2 | ### 3
3 | ########## 10
4 | # 1
5 | 0
6 | ##### 5
```

---

If you make improvements to your code, feel free to create a new question with your improved code. Just make sure that it functions as intended, otherwise, you risk getting flagged for being off-topic.

Comment: I know that it is well intentioned, but you wouldn't have to post an answer. It doesn't help either him or the site.

Comment: "With a  std::map<int, int> you need to set keys to zero in a loop." wrong. If `operator[]` doesn't find the value you're looking at, the entry is created with default constructor, so `0` in this case.

Comment: @Calak disagree. Provides several useful facts for the OP. An overly draconian reading of the faq is not helpful to the site.

Comment: @MartinYork I don't says it's bad to try to help, I wanted to post reply too, but restricted myself because the off-topic-ness of the post. It help nor the site (what a fest, if everybody try to give useful answer to all off-topic post), nor the OP, nor the answerer. Giving credit to this kind of response if a bad thing, IMHO.

Comment: I fixed the output of the code based on this answer. And I am going to choose it as the best answer.

Comment: @ChubakBidpaa People will blame me again for this but, can you read : [What should I not do?](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)